# jQuery close all open menus

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I have created a menu for a responsive site and all works how I want, however when you open a second sub menu the others stay open.

Is there an easy way to close all open menus before opening the current one.

This is my menu structure:

```
<ul id="menumain">
   <li class="MenuLevelOne"><a href="brandon-news.php">News</a></li>
   <li class="MenuLevelOne"><a href="businesses.php">Businesses</a></li>
   <li class="MenuLevelOne"><a href="events.php">Events</a></li>
   <li class="MenuLevelOne"><a href="webcams.php">Webcams</a></li>
   <li class="MenuLevelOne MenuDD"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">History</a>
      <ul class="MenuLevelTwo">
         <li><a href="webcams.php">Brief History</a></li>
         <li><a href="webcams.php">Brandon at War</a></li>
         <li><a href="webcams.php">Heritage Centre</a></li>
         <li><a href="webcams.php">Historic Maps</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="MenuLevelOne MenuDD"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Community</a>
      <ul class="MenuLevelTwo">
         <li><a href="webcams.php">Brief History</a></li>
         <li><a href="webcams.php">Brandon at War</a></li>
         <li><a href="webcams.php">Heritage Centre</a></li>
         <li><a href="webcams.php">Historic Maps</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the jQuery code:

```
$(".MenuDD").click(function () {
        $(this).find("ul").toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("darkbg");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".MenuDD").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().find("ul").hide();
    $(this).find("ul").toggle();
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('darkbg');
    $(this).toggleClass("darkbg");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5jj77/1/)**

Comment: That's almost perfect apart from the darkbg toggleClass not being cleared. Any ideas how to make that change as well?

Comment: That should be done using  `$(this).siblings().removeClass('darkbg')`

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all sub menu `.MenuLevelTwo` when your list item is clicked and only show the sub menu under clicked list item:

```
$(".MenuDD").click(function () {
    var submenu = $(this).find("ul");
    $('.MenuDD ul').not(submenu).hide();
    $(this).find("ul").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("darkbg");
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tG3c3/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(".MenuDD").click(function () {
    $('.MenuDD ul').hide();
    $(this).find("ul").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("darkbg");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#">SUBMENU1</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">M11</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">M12</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">M13</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">M14</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">SUBMENU2</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">M21</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">M22</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">M23</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">M24</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery:**

```
 $('#list > li').siblings().find('ul').hide();
        $('#list > li').click(function () {
            if($(this).find('ul').is(':visible'))
            {
                $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
            }
            else{
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp();
            $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
            }
        });
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/2QKe9/2/